# Why is my Vue app redirecting to my Home route on refresh of any page?

Tags: vue.js, express, vue-router

This is similar to a lot of questions asked re: setting up Vue Router with an Express server using the connect-history-api-fallback middleware as directed in the [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), but I’m still running into two issues:

1. When I refresh any page, I am redirected to my Home route (e.g. http://localhost:8080/451)
2. When I enter a direct link in the address bar (e.g. http://localhost:8080/451/alerts), I am also redirected to my Home route

I am not receiving a “Cannot GET /” error, so I am pretty confident that connect-history-api-fallback is implemented correctly.

For context, this is what my router looks like:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: __dirname,
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      component: Home,
      name: 'home',
      path: '/:siteId',
    },
    {
      component: SuperAdmin,
      name: 'super-admin',
      path: '/:siteId/super-admin',
    },
    {
      component: Alerts,
      name: 'alerts',
      path: '/:siteId/alerts',
    },
    {
      component: LPRAdmin,
      name: 'lpr-admin',
      path: '/:siteId/lpr-admin',
    },
    {
      component: ControlCenterAdmin,
      name: 'control-center-admin',
      path: '/:siteId/control-center-admin',
    },
  ],
});
```

And this is my configuration in the server:

```
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static('build/public');
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  verbose: true,
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
```

Has anyone dealt with and solved this or a similar issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `...`? It's not obvious that `/451/alerts` should be anything but home.

Comment: Pretty sure that refreshing the browser resets/reinitializes the Vue app by default.  Possibly this has something to do with the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @EstusFlask that is the rest of my routes that I figured were irrelevant, but I see how that would be confusing! Just updated the code.

Comment: @Tim the routing actually worked fine until we implemented our authentication + server, so I don't think that's the cause, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem to either front or back end. /451/alerts should respond with 200 and index.html contents, that's a proper setup for SPA, you can check this in devtools. If it redirects to root or else then you have server problem. What is `history`? Why do you have staticFileMiddleware twice?

Comment: @EstusFlask /451/alerts does respond with 200 and index.html contents. `history` is connect-history-api-fallback and `staticFileMiddleware` is implemented per the [documentation examples](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/tree/master/examples/static-files-and-index-rewrite)

Comment: If there's no redirect then server side is ok and the problem is in front router. What was the reasoning for `base: __dirname`? It shouldn't be there.

Comment: @EstusFlask It's just the base URL of our app per the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base)

Comment: http://localhost:8080/451/alerts has no base url, so there shouldn't be `base`. I'm not sure what __dirname resolves to in Vue files as it's Node variable, but I'm quite sure it will mess up the router.

Comment: @EstusFlask it resolves to "/" in this instance. I did remove `base: __dirname` just to try it out, and I do still experience the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future, we were able to solve it! Somewhat embarrassingly, we forgot we were rerouting users to the home page after authentication every time the app mounted. We removed

```
this.$router.push(`/${siteId}`);
```

from our App.js and the issues are resolved!